# i can't send any email verification notification in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel-9

I tried a lot of things throughout the project to figure out why I can't send a confirmation email :) and after all my journey, I realized that my attribute prefix (us_email) is not allowed and I have to write it as "email".
even tried to overwrite getEmailForVerification function, but it doesn't worked

```
public function getEmailForVerification(): string
{
    return $this->us_email;
}
```

is there any way to use this "us_" prefix as my email attribute name and send email verification notification?

Answer (score 0):

WooooW, i found the solution
i use "Accessors & Mutators". its look like i set an alias name for my us_email field

```
public function email(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn($email) => $this->us_email,
        set: fn($email) => $this->us_email = $email
    );
}
```